# Generating a comma separated list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a comma separated list of data values to use in a graph, but the way that I know of to create such a list causes an issue if the value of one of the points is the same as the final point.

For example, the following methods have both produced a result that doesn't work.

```
data: [<% @data.each do |point| %><%= point.value %><%= "," unless point == @data.last) %><% end %>]
data: [<% @data.each do |point| %><%= point.value %><%= "," unless point.eql?(@data.last) %><% end %>]
```

note how below if the value of a point is the same as the last, the comma is skipped.

```
                                               vv
data: [0.069,0.174,0.034,0.112,0.598,0.043,0.0370.395,1.509,0.052,0.045,0.405,0.11,0.173,0.039,0.517,0.075,0.043,0.037]
```

I know that my problem is that I'm checking if the values are the same, but how can I check to see if the objects themselves are the same?

Comment: Is the output some kind of standard format? It looks like YAML, perhaps, in which case you should just use YAML from the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
@data.map(&:value).join(',')
```

Comment: Aren't you excluding the last value from being added now tho?